# Format file input in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

For the following  type of file

```
Hannover Magdeburg 148
Bremen Dortmund 23
Hannover Kassel 165
Magdeburg Berlin 166
```

How can I store the values like

```
my_dictionary= 
{"from":Hannover,
"to":Magdeburg,
"distance":148
}
```

all in a same dictionary/list/tuple

---

```
<pre>with open('input1.txt') as my_file:
    lines=my_file.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    print lines[i]

my_file.close()
my_tuple={}
for i in range(len(lines)):
    j=0
    my_list = lines[i].split(' ',1)
    my_tuple["from"]=my_list[j]
    my_tuple["to"][i]=my_list[j+1]
    my_tuple["distance"][i]=my_list[j+2]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    print my_list['from'][i]</pre>
```

Comment: What did you try? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: sorry for that .This is my first question in stack overflow . I will be accustomed to it .

Answer (score 1):

```
data = '''Hannover Magdeburg 148
Bremen Dortmund 23
Hannover Kassel 165
Magdeburg Berlin 166'''
data = data.split()
data = [data[i:i + 3] for i in xrange(0, len(data), 3)]
# [['Hannover', 'Magdeburg', '148'], ['Bremen', 'Dortmund', '23'], ['Hannover', 'Kassel', '165'], ['Magdeburg', 'Berlin', '166']]
data = [{k: v for (k, v) in zip(('from', 'to', 'distance'), el)}
        for el in data]
print data

[{'distance': '148', 'from': 'Hannover', 'to': 'Magdeburg'},
 {'distance': '23', 'from': 'Bremen', 'to': 'Dortmund'},
 {'distance': '165', 'from': 'Hannover', 'to': 'Kassel'},
 {'distance': '166', 'from': 'Magdeburg', 'to': 'Berlin'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictReader` can do the work for you:

```
import csv
import pprint

with open('data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames='from to distance'.split(),delimiter=' ')
    L = list(reader)

pprint.pprint(L)
```

Output:

```
[{'distance': '148', 'from': 'Hannover', 'to': 'Magdeburg'},
 {'distance': '23', 'from': 'Bremen', 'to': 'Dortmund'},
 {'distance': '165', 'from': 'Hannover', 'to': 'Kassel'},
 {'distance': '166', 'from': 'Magdeburg', 'to': 'Berlin'}]
```